# How to dispose TiledTextureRegion in Andengine

Tags: android, memory-leaks, andengine

I am developing a game where I display different sprites on a scene on touch. Each scene has a set of (about 10 sprites) that gets displayed and removed based on user actions. When user navigates to next scenes, I load the sprites for that scene and remove the sprites for the first scene from the cache. I notice a small memory leak on scene change and pin pointed to TiledTextureRegion  variables created on 1s scene.

I tried sprite.reset() call but that did not help. I am removing sprites from the scene. This is how the remove sprite code looks like:

```
    private void removeSprite(final AnimatedSprite sprite) {
    final PhysicsConnector facePhysicsConnector = this.mPhysicsWorld.getPhysicsConnectorManager().findPhysicsConnectorByShape(sprite);

    this.mPhysicsWorld.unregisterPhysicsConnector(facePhysicsConnector);
    this.mPhysicsWorld.destroyBody(facePhysicsConnector.getBody());

    this.mScene.unregisterTouchArea(sprite);
    this.mScene.detachChild(sprite);

    System.gc();
}
```

But looks like its not clearing TiledTextureRegion objected associated with sprite. Since, I will have lot of different scenes in the app, I am worried memory leak would add up and cause issues. 
Any ideas or suggestions will be highly appreciated. 
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't clear `TiledTextureRegion` but you can clear `BitmapTextureAtlas` using `BitmapTextureAtlas.unload();`.

For example:

```
BitmapTextureAtlas Texture1 = new BitmapTextureAtlas(null, 1024, 1024, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(Texture7);
ITextureRegion example = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(Texture1, this, "picture.png", 0, 0);
```

And then, when you need:

```
Texture1.unload();
```

But probable you don't need to clear memory, because you will use your TiledTextureRegion again. You will recreate your TiledTextureRegion and it will slowdown your application.

Comment: Thanks....I was worried about storing lot of TiledTextureRegion  in cache as it will take lot of memory..but end up doing what you suggested and caching all TiledTextureRegion.